# Vertical inner rounded ProgressBar with text in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, progress-bar, android-progressbar

**How can i achieve this type of vertical progress bar?The progress bar's progress also has round corner**[image: vertical progress bar]

**I tried to find solution but can not find any.I tried to set a custom drawable as follow**`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:centerColor="#ffffffff"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ffffffff"
                android:startColor="#ffffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/xxs" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#E9E9E9"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#E9E9E9"
                    android:startColor="#E9E9E9" />
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/xxs" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go with the some chart library that would be great solution but if you want to go with customisation your chart then go with below code.

**veritcal_progressbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
     <shape>
         <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
         <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
         <stroke
             android:width="1dp"
             android:color="#FF000000" />
     </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
     <clip
         android:clipOrientation="vertical"
         android:gravity="bottom">
         <shape>
             <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
             <solid android:color="#FFBE00"/>
             <stroke
                 android:width="1dp"
                 android:color="#FF000000" />
         </shape>
     </clip>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Use in layout file.

```
<ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/vprogressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/veritcal_progressbar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.But the inner progress thumb also need  to be rounded like when it is 55% progress .Is it possible?See the image i provide.The 20% progress also have a rounded column

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="100.0"
        android:value="60.0"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:scaleY="15"
        app:thumbRadius="0dp"
        app:haloRadius="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="60%"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output
[image]